# Cypress.io - typing into input from `then`

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have form to test, that I would like to check if inputs have required fields and some other custom behaviors.

I am querying the input like this:

```
cy.get('#input_id').then(($input) => {
  // My assertions here  
});
```

My question is, how can I type into the input from within a function passed to `.then`?

I found `root` method, byt when I console log it from within `then`, I get that `root()` is the `document` itself.

Comment: You can `cy.wrap($input).type('some text')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RichardMatsen mentioned, you can use [`wrap`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html) function to get the element obtained from `then`.

Cypress docs mentions the usage of [`wrap` on Elements](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Elements) as :

> Wrap elements to continue executing commands

So all you need to do is :

```
cy.wrap($input).type('Input Text')
```